# pdflatex error in Inlage Editor - Command line compiler

Tags: errors, miktex

I have installed MikTeX and [Inlage LaTeX editor](http://www.inlage.com/home) for intellisense LaTeX programming. To convert it to pdf when I click the convert icon, it displays me `pdflatex.exe not found`. I changed the path of the compiler, but it didn't work. Is there a command line compiler for generating pdf documents of LaTeX ?

Comment: How did you change the path? Did you use `Build` → `Compiler Options`? In the window that appears, select `Compiler`? There you have to change. By default it is `C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9` If yours is 32 bit windows, remove `(x86)`. Did you try compiling from command prompt? Go to the folder of your tex file and issue `pdflatex yourfile`. `Yourfile` is actually `yourfile.tex`. What did you get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inlage, by default, has this path: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9`, which is true if you install a 64 bit windows. On the 32 bit windows, you have make it like `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9` i.e, without `(x86)`. This can be done in the following manner.

Go to `Build` → `Compiler Options` and choose `Compiler`. This window will open:

[image]

Here you can change the path. Don't forget to save after you made changes.

If you want to compile from command line (which isn't what I advice) do the following:
Assuming that your file is in `D:\my tex folder`,

1. Open command window and  navigate to `D:\my tex folder`
2. Issue `pdflatex myfile` where `myfile` is `myfile.tex`, your tex file.

Things should work. If not some thing is wrong in your tex distribution.

Hope this is helpful.